# Chromium Issue - SCSS Transition on :hover leaving box shadow artifact

Tags: css, sass, css-transitions, chromium

I've noticed an issue that doesn't seem to be happening in Firefox, only Chrome and Edge, so presumably chromium browsers.

I'm trying to create a nav bar, where each link element has a hover animation, changing color and with a box-shadow underline, which should disappear when not hovering over the link.

In regular CSS, this worked as expected, however using SCSS the box-shadow underline leaves a faint underline artifact even when not hovering over the link. Even more weirdly, if I switch to another tab, then back again, the faint underline disappears.

Does anyone have any ideas why this is the case?

Here's a link to a code-pen: https://codepen.io/signetohara-the-bashful/pen/yLJqoaL

HTML:

```
    <nav class="navbar">
      <div class="navCenter">
        <ul class="navLinks">
          <li>
            <a href="">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

SCSS:

```
*,
::after,
::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Yantramanav", sans-serif;
  background: #e8f1f5;
  color: #000;
  margin-top: 5rem;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.navbar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 200;
  background: #fafafa;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
}

.navCenter {
  width: 90vw;
  max-width: 73.125rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.navLinks {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;

   li {
     margin-right: 2rem;
   }

   a {
     text-decoration: none;
     text-transform: capitalize;
     color: #000;
     font-weight: bold;
     letter-spacing: 0.5rem;
     transition: all 0.3s linear;
     padding: 0.5rem 0;
   }

   a:hover {
     box-shadow: 0px 2px #00d7ff;
     color: #00d7ff;
   }
}
```

Comment: It is working in codepen. Is it creating problem only in chromium or firefox.

Comment: Hi Bharti, it appears the problem is only showing on Chromium browsers. Firefox does not have the issue, but Chrome and Edge do.